# Getting error : Unable to Use Amazon Authorization Manager. APIKey is incorrect or does not exist

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am trying to use Amazon Alexa in my android App.
I have added api_key.txt in my asset folder but still getting above error.

Answer (score 1):

the api_key should be generated from the android developer site withe the MD5 and SHA-256 of your application then only it will work properly. Check the link for detailed information.
https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/getting-started-with-the-alexa-voice-service

Answer (score 0):

We just need to correct the android applicationID ID with applicationID mentioned in amazon developer portal.

In Android Studio Right click 'app'>Open Module Settings>Flavors
The "Application Id" should be match

Amazon Developer Console>Alexa>Alexa Voice Service>Your Registered Products>Security Profile>Android/Kindle Settings>Package

Comment: the api_key should be generated from the android developer site withe the MD5 and SHA-256 of your application then only it will work properly. Check the link for detailed information https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/getting-started-with-the-alexa-voice-service